# How to install flashplugin-installer and ttf-mscorefonts-installer using apt-cacher-ng?

Tags: networking, proxy, flash, apt-cacher-ng

On my network i use apt-cacher-ng on server and add 
`Acquire::http { Proxy "http://[10.48.21.23]:3142"; };` 
to /etc/apt/apt.conf on clients.

So apt-get can't download file through proxy with wget.

Comment: Isn't there a flash plugin package containing actual flash in the Partner repository? That would fix half the problem, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-cacher-ng` shouldn't interfere with the actual package download. The problem with these two packages is they don't actually contain their payload. They are both lightweight packages that contain scripts to download extra data with `wget` when you install them.

This is simply for legal reasons. The extra files licenses' conflict with the repo's.

If you need to force these downloads through a proxy too, you can, either by setting up wget's proxy settings in `/etc/wgetrc`:

```
http_proxy = http://proxy-ip:8080/
```

Or you can use the longhand command to pass the proxy through to it:

```
sudo http_proxy=http://proxy-ip:8080 apt-get install flashplugin-installer ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/362970

The proxy address I'm talking about in these solutions should *not* be `apt-cache-ng` - that's only for caching package downloads. I'm talking about the same proxy that you'd use in your browser, for example.

Comment: OK it work, but i had scripts using wget to download files on local server and they don't work. The second solution work but my users can't do it. Thank you for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

I put:

```
use_proxy = on
no_proxy = 10.*.*.*,localhost
http_proxy = http://proxy.company.com:8080/
https_proxy = http://proxy.company.com:8080/
proxy_user = XXX
proxy_password = YYY
```

to **/etc/wgetrc** for permanent settings.

Seems that

```
Acquire::http::Proxy
```

from **/etc/apt/apt.conf** doesn't used by downloaders...

Comment: http://linux.lsdev.sil.org/wiki/index.php/MSCoreFonts_and_proxy